# How to check User Data status while launching the instance in aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to launch aws instance with User Data. My User Data is a server installation process and i have to check whether the user data scripts are executed properly. Is there any option to check if the status of User data is completed ? I need to know the status since from that launched instance i am taking another image. As off now, i explicitly used time.sleep(90) for my process completion.

Note:
I am using Boto library.

Any solution on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you define "executed properly"?  Do you simply want to know when the initialization script completes?  What process is doing the checking?  Is it running on the same instance or somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe write a log to indicate a checkpointing.

Comment: ec2conn.run_instances(ami, instance_type=instance_type, placement=placement, user_data=script, security_groups=security_groups)

Comment: where script="my backend user scripts to be executed"

Comment: I need to check weather my users scripts completed or not with status code .(success or failure)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## UPDATE

What I landed up doing was creating a marker file at the end of the user-data run. I had the node controller spawn one ssh session per ec2 node and run a simple busy-wait loop as a command on the other end, so it only returns when the file is created. I then just wait() for all the ssh sessions to exit or until the wait timeout occurs.

It's ugly, but it works. It's very frustrating that EC2 doesn't provide better facilities for signalling status from within instances.

### Labels

One possible approach is to have the instance's user-data script add an additional label to the instance when it completes. You can poll the instance with `update` or do a describe-instances with a filter that includes only nodes with the tag you use to specify that user data has been updated.

This requires that you include a limited API key and secret in your user-data scripts when you send them. *Don't* use your regular api key and secret, make one with very limited IAM rights. Additionally the user-data script will probably want to delete its self when it's done.

### SNS / SQS

I've also considered using the Simple Notification Service and/or SQS for this, but it seems like overkill.

Like setting tags it requires that the instance have its own EC2 credentials.

SNS is push-only, so you have to have an endpoint reachable by EC2. That's a pain. SQS is pull, but doesn't have message routing, so you need one queue per set of nodes you're bringing up. You have to pass the unique queue name into the instance or have the instance use EC2 credentials to query it from a tag, then have the instance use that particular queue.

So, yeah, a pain.

### Console

Getting console output won't work, EC2 stops updating it shortly after the instance transitions to the 'running' state.

There doesn't appear to be any way, instance- or client-side, to force an update.

### Marker file

When the cloud-init script finishes it can `touch` a marker file somewhere shell-accessible to the normal user. This is a bit annoying, as it requires ssh'ing into every node and then polling for the creation of the marker file. The pain of polling can be somewhat reduced by use of a loop like:

```
while ! test -e 'cloud-init-complete'
do
    inotifywait -qq -t 2 -e create -e moved_to . ||true
done
```

after the installation of the inotify-tools package. If you don't burn inotify-tools into your AMIs you'll want to replace `inotifywait` with a simple `sleep` and accept the extra latency, or do:

```
while ! test -e 'cloud-init-complete'
do
    if test -x /usr/bin/inotifywait; then
        inotifywait -qq -t 2 -e create -e moved_to . ||true
    else
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

This still requires an ssh connection to each server, though, and that's a pain to monitor and poll.

### Something smarter?

My dream solution is being able to send an additional request to the EC2 metadata service to set a special instance tag or custom extra status field.

Comment: awsome, In case if someone looking to have the same option in terraforms https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724265/3288890

Answer (score 1):

You use EC2 API Tools and log User Data output or just check `ec2-get-console-output`. Refer to this article: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output

Sorry, not sure about Boto

In your user-data script you log result to log-file. Once Instance is started, you check the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ec2-get-console-output` won't do the trick. EC2 stops updating console output shortly after the instance enters the 'running state and doesn't update it again until the instance changes state.

Comment: Just log your user-data result to log file.

Comment: That doesn't let a remote tool see the status without ssh'ing in and polling a logfile on the instance, which is a pain in terms of credentials management, security, automation, etc.

Comment: It is not pain. You have to deploy your public key to your AMI. After that, just `ssh [your-instance-address] cat /var/log/user-data.log > /tmp/user-data.log`

Comment: Locally polling the cloud-init logs doesn't meet my needs in terms of ease of scaling to larger instance counts, automation, etc. In any case, I was commenting on your original answer, which will not work, not the edited suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`InstaceStatusOk` [Waiter](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters) waits until UserData script has completed:

```py
waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=['i-12345'])
```

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk

Comment: Waiting for the instance status check to be OK does not guarantee that the User Data script has completed.

Comment: A better variant of this could implement a heartbeat instead I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Amazon Linux, you can use a `chkconfig` script in `/etc/init.d` with a `Required-Start` directive:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig:   345 95 95
# description: Description

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: userdatainit
# Description: Wait for user data
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Required-Start: cloud-init
# Required-Stop:
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Do work here, will happen -after- UserData script/config."
    ;;
  stop)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

If you have saved this as a file like `/etc/init.d/afteruserdata`, then register it like so:

```
chown root:root /etc/init.d/afteruserdata
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/afteruserdata
chkconfig --add afteruserdata
chkconfig --level 345 afteruserdata on
```

Then you can create the AMI and your code will run *after* the `UserData` script.

**Caveat**: `cloud-init` only does its thing the first time you boot an instance from the AMI.